# Paypal payment is not redirecting to the right url in MVC .Net

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, paypal

Currenty I am implementing a third party payment system through paypal in my MVC application. I have created the payment details are getting through, but at the start of the method when checking if the user is logged in or not (currently the user is not logged in) the redirection link rel is not being appruval_url but it is giving self. Below is the code that I currently have.

This code is set in a controller being called by a button.

```
//Controller code
// Paypal Payment
    private Payment payment;
    // Create a payment using APIContext
    private Payment CreatePayment(APIContext apiContext, string redirectUrl)
    {
        var listItems = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() };
        listItems.items.Add(new Item()
        {
            name = "M&Ms",
            currency = "EUR",
            price = "0.7",
            quantity = "5",
            sku = "sku"
        });

        var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };

        var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
        {
            cancel_url = redirectUrl,
            return_url = redirectUrl
        };

        // Create detials object
        var details = new Details()
        {
            tax = "0",
            shipping = "0",
            subtotal = "3.5"
        };

        // Create amount object
        var amount = new Amount()
        {
            currency = "EUR",
            total = "3.5",
            details = details
        };

        var transectionList = new List<Transaction>();
        transectionList.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            description = "Testing transection",
            invoice_number = Convert.ToString((new Random().Next(100000))),
            amount = amount,
            item_list = listItems
        });

        payment = new Payment()
        {
            intent = "sale",
            payer = payer,
            transactions = transectionList,
            redirect_urls = redirUrls
        };

        return payment.Create(apiContext);
    }

    // Create Execute Payment method
    private Payment ExecutePayment(APIContext apiContext, string payerid, string paymentId)
    {
        var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution()
        {
            payer_id = payerid
        };

        payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };

        return payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
    }

    // Create Payment with Paypal
    public ActionResult PaymentWithPaypal()
    {
        APIContext apiContext = PaypalConfiguration.GetAPIContext();

        try
        {
            string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
            {
                // Creating payment
                string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Orders/Index.aspx?";
                var guid = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000));
                var createdPayment = CreatePayment(apiContext, baseURI + "guid=" + guid);

                // Gets links returned from Paypal response to create call function
                var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();
                string paypalRedirectUrl = string.Empty;

                while (links.MoveNext())
                {
                    Links link = links.Current;
                    var temp = link.rel.ToLower().Trim();
                    if (link.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("appruval_url"))
                    {
                        paypalRedirectUrl = link.href;
                    }
                    Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
                    return Redirect(paypalRedirectUrl);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var guid = Request.Params["guid"];
                var executedPayment = ExecutePayment(apiContext, payerId, Session[guid] as string); 
                if (executedPayment.state.ToLower() != "approved")
                {
                    return View("Failure");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            PaypalLogger.Log("Error: " + e.Message);
            return View("Failure");
        }

        return View("Success");
    }


    // webconfig code
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" 
    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

    <!-- Paypal & Log4net -->
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->  
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" />
      <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000" />
      <add name="requestRetries" value="1" />
      <add name="clientId" value="AdzOKk5M7yVA_dWjifjTs6rSAZX9pCRJ7xJ5wX4e_TikEPieiGBJwuMz8h4Su0UVpPVIB5IMgghc7XvZ" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="EEmh_b6MxGLxNNjbI4E-eW96MluwGd0TxU_Ex8Rehyk4yoeHWfiRaS4ERlAVfFrq_izauhIWZukhJ8At" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
```

Comment: `appruval_url"` where I come from, it is spelled "approval"... By the way, you should **NEVER** post your client ID and secret. I recommend deleting this question entirely and starting a new one without those details.

Comment: I have tried it correct way. The problem is that when I check the value of temp it is giving "self" and not "approval_url". Thank you for the clientID and secretId but this is only for testing